# Call to a member function getNum() on null in a choice_value form definition

Tags: symfony

I encountered an issue with my form definition, it was working fine (at least this part) and now it's not.
I must have changed something elsewhere but I don't have a clue where to look at...

Maybe your experienced eyes will catch the obvious thing I'm missing...

here is the part of the form builder :

```
            ->add('departement', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Dept',
                'label' => "* Département :",
                'choice_label' => function ($dept) {
                    return $dept->getNum() . " - " . $dept->getName();
                },
                'choice_value' => function ($dept) {
                    **return $dept->getNum();**
                },
                'placeholder' => '...'
            ))
```

The issue occurs on the "return $dept->getNum();" line, the choice_label is very similar but doesn't throw any error.
I've checked the db and the Dept data seem to be OK.

What am I missing now ?

Thank you

**EDIT 1**

As temporary workaround, I've added :

```
                    if ($dept !== null) {
                        return $dept->getNum();
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
```

it works, but it's not satisfying...

**EDIT 2**

Now my form is displaying, but when I try to submit it, I got the following error :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO cheval_ticketadd
>   (title, firstname, lastname, child, student, price, departement,
>   email, group, contact_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with
>   params ["M", "dsqf", "qsdf", 1, 0, 8, {}, "qsdf@qsdf.qdsf", 0, 53]:

It's trying to record {} as "departement" value.

**EDIT 3**

Well, I managed to find why the record was not working : I was using a SQL reserved name for an entity field : group. Yeah, I know, it's dumb.
So I have it working now, but I still don't know why my very first problem appeared, if anyone have a clue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your Dept class looks like, but let's say it was like this:

```
class Dept
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="stu_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $dept_id;
    ...
    protected $dept_name;
    ...
    protected $dept_num;
    ...
}
```

Then in your form, since you are using EntityType, you can simply set the choice label and value like so:

```
->add('departement', EntityType::class, array(
      'class' => 'AppBundle:Dept',
      'label' => "* Département :",
      'choice_label' => 'dept_name',
      'choice_value' => 'dept_num',
      'placeholder' => '...'
))
```

This is a lot simpler that what you are tying to do in your original posting. I think this should work, let me know if you have problems.

Comment: Actually, in the choice_label, I want to display like this : "num - name" so I think I don't have much choice, but for the choice_value, you are absolutely right, I don't need any function, so it works as you said. Still I'd like to know why it won't work since it worked before... Anyway thanks for your answer :)

Comment: In fact, it's not OK... My form is displaying as I want, this part is working now, but when I submit it, it's trying to record {} as value and I got a SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you actually have 2 questions, I wanted to answer your second question here.

You second question is, why doesn't this work:

```
'choice_value' => function ($dept) {
  return $dept->getNum();
},
```

This is answered by the documentation here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label

So normally you would use "$key, $value, $index" which references the determined "choices" array. Each one of those is key words, so you don't try to redeclare "$key" for example.

If you read further down in the above link, you see this:

> If your choice values are objects, then choice_label can also be a
>   property path. Imagine you have some Status class with a
>   getDisplayName() method:

Which is applicable in your case, since you are using the `AppBundle:Dept` class, and you want to get the department number. So you can reference the field directly. Like so:

```
'choice_value' => 'dept_num'
```

Which is my first answer.

So hopefully that makes senses. If you think this answered your "second" question, can you upvote. Thank you!